# ¿Cómo enviar json encode por ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

Estoy intentando enviar un objeto en json:

```
{
  'salario' : 0,
  'usuario' : {
    'nombre' : 'usuario1',
    'bono' : null,    
    'uf' : null,
    'ultimaRenta' : 1698567,
    'utm' : null
  },
  'empleado' : 12,
  'param' : {    
    'movilizacion' : 46786.0
  },
  'ahorro' : 84525
}
```

En un ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url : url2,
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            type : 'POST',
            data : jsonEnviado,
            jsonpCallback : "myJSON",
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var rentaFinal = data.renta;
                var num = data.renta;
                num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(
                        /(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
                num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
                rentaFinal = num;

                document.getElementById('renta').innerHTML = "$" +  rentaFinal;
            }
        });
```

Pero al capturarlo desde el controller, el objeto viene `null`

la firma del método es: `public String calculaRenta(HttpServletRequest req){`

Y estoy obteniendo el objeto con: `req.getParameter("jsonEnviado");`

He buscado la forma de hacer un encode pero no me ha resultado.

Comment: Yo no se de jsp, pero infiriendo por el nombre de la función `getParameter` más bien deberías mandar el nombre del parámetro `data` en vez del nombre de la variable `jsonEnviado`, `getParametero('data')? sobre todo porque al llegar al controlador ese nombre deja de existir y solamente es el objeto JSON

Comment: Pensé en eso por un momento pero aún cuando utilizo `req.getParameter("data");` el resultado es un `null`...

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando un Servlet?

Comment: Intenta en vez de enviar `data:jsonEnviado,` enviar `data: {jsonEnviado : JSON.stringify(jsonEnviado) }` y dinos que ocurre.

Comment: Sí, estoy usando un servlet @DarthVader

Comment: @Einer resuelto, al agregarle data: `{jsonEnviado : JSON.stringify(jsonEnviado)}` a la llamada del ajax pude obtener los valores y castear el objeto son problemas. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta en vez de enviar:

```
 data:jsonEnviado
```

Enviar:

```
data: {jsonEnviado : JSON.stringify(jsonEnviado) }
```

Esto para que el json se convierta en un parametro del request y puedas hacer la conversion en el servidor.